# Declaring variables in Power Query M Functions

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am trying to create a reusable function in Power Query that will be used by several tables.

This works well (written in blank query):

```
let
    is_emergency = (color as text) => 
    if color = "red" or color = "orange" then 
       "emergency" 
    else 
        "not emergency"  
in
    is_emergency
```

I can call it using a custom column like this `=emergency([color_column])`.

However - my color column contains a lot of extra spaces so I somehow need to call `Text.Trim()` on the color-parameter. How to write this?

What I thought would work was to just write this:

```
let
    is_emergency = (color as text) =>
    color = Text.Trim(color, " "),
    if color = "red" or color = "orange" then 
       "emergency" 
    else 
        "not emergency"  
in
    is_emergency
```

but this gives me the error `Token Literal Expected`.

How to write it proper? I am aware I can use the Power Query GUI to create simple functions like this, but my real case is more advanced and I would like to understand the `M` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself after some research.

```
let
    is_emergency = (color as text) =>
    // you need to put the variable declaration inside a new let - in
    let 
        trimmed_color = Text.Trim(color, " "), 
        // you also need to define the return value and return it in the new let - in
        return_value = if trimmed_color = "red" or trimmed_color = "orange" then 
            "emergency" 
        else 
            "not emergency"
    in
        return_value
in
    is_emergency
```